# Question about Splitting Field Extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

When studying normal closures, I came across the following in the proof for the existence of normal closures for finite extensions:

If $K \overset{i}\rightarrow L$ is finite, $g \in K[X]$ and $L \overset{j}\rightarrow F$ is a splitting field extension for $i(g) \in L[X]$, then $K \overset{j \circ i}\rightarrow F$ is a splitting field extension for $g$.

Could anyone please direct me to a proof for this or be kind enough to explain why this is true?

Comment: A "splitting field extension for $g$" basically just means "a field extension which contains all of the roots of $g$". So, take any root $r$ of $g$. Then $r$ is also a root of $i(g)$, so...

Comment: @diracdeltafunk In our definition, the splitting field extension is an extension over which the polynomial splits and which has no proper intermediate extensions that split the polynomial. So, I understand that I can prove that $K \overset{j \circ i}\rightarrow F$ is an extension over which $g$ splits, but I cannot see why minimality is true. (Edit: Included tags)

Comment: Oh, this does not necessarily hold. For example, what if $L$ already properly contains a splitting field of $g$? E.g. $K = \mathbb{Q}$, $g = x^2-2$, $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.